# Cannot resolve symbol R in android studio

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

I add a new menu res(add.xml)  to my android project and I am getting Cannot resolve symbol R in the all my java file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_save"
        android:title="@string/action_save"
        app:showAsAction="always" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_discard"
        android:title="@string/action_discard"
        app:showAsAction="never" />
</menu>
```

I have tried 
Build > Clean project and 
Tools > Android > Sync Project with Grade Files
but none work

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/885009/r-cannot-be-resolved-android-error

Comment: Sometimes simply restarting your Android Studio and rebuilding gradle will  fix the problem. Try it, nothing you can lose. Weird bug, happened to me a couple of times... :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to everyone. 
I have been able to solve the problem by renaming the xml file from add.xml to another name. I guess the name add.xml is conflict with another internal file name

Answer (score 0):

Check for the `/res` directory. Usually this is caused by a problem in your XML files, or some missing resource.
Also, check at the top of your file, maybe there is this line:

```
import android.R
```

this can happen when the IDE auto-generate your imports.